# Sharepoint list not updating fully with PowerApps combo box: How do I fix the issue?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

**COMBO BOX not updating Sharepoint List**

I am using a combo box to update a column in a sharepoint list.  I am using the DefaultSelectedItems property.  If I select multiple options, it works.  If I try to edit my selection using the combo box, it updates the sharepoint list, but it cuts off the first option.

I selected 3 options from the combo box, and the list updates correctly.  When I try to edit my combo box selection and save again, the list updates, but it cuts off the first selection I would have made.

[Initial Service selection using combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEdRq.png)

[Sharepoint list matches combo box selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMV5j.png)

[Edit of original combo box choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7AIK.png)

[Shrepoint list not matching my combo box choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6plw.png)